# CakePHP 3.4 use setTemplates() multiple times

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.4

I'm trying to use `setTemplates()` multiple times in a view, but it doesn't work as expected.

I have two templates which I want to set when I need them.

```
$bootstrapTemplate = [
    'inputContainer' => '<div class="form-group {{type}}{{required}}">{{content}}</div>',
];

$bootstrapTemplateInputGroup = [
    'inputContainer' => '<div class="form-group {{type}}{{required}}">{{content}}</div>',
    'input' => '<div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-addon">€</div><input type="{{type}}" name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}/></div>'
];
```

I start to set the templates like this

```
$this->Form->setTemplates($bootstrapTemplate);

$this->Form->control('title', ['class' => 'form-control', 'label' => __('Titel')]);

// OUTPUT - correct
// <div class="form-group text required"><label for="title">Titel</label><input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" required="required" maxlength="255" id="title"></div>

$this->Form->setTemplates($bootstrapTemplateInputGroup);
echo $this->Form->control('price', ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'price_eur', 'label' => __('Preis EUR')]).'</div>';

// OUTPUT - correct
<div class="form-group number required"><label for="price_eur">Preis EUR</label><div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-addon">€</div><input type="number" name="price" class="form-control" id="price_eur" required="required" step="any"></div></div>
```

Now I want to switch back to `$bootstrapTemplate` which doesn't seem to work. Instead the `$bootstrapTemplateInputGroup` is used

```
$this->Form->setTemplates($bootstrapTemplate);
echo $this->Form->control('user_zip', ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'user_zip', 'label' => __('PLZ')])

// OUTPUT - wrong
<div class="form-group text"><label for="user_zip">PLZ</label><div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-addon">€</div><input type="text" name="user_zip" class="form-control" id="user_zip"></div></div>
```

My expected output is the template of `$bootstrapTemplate` like:

```
<div class="form-group text required"><label for="user_zip">PLZ</label><input type="text" name="user_zip" class="form-control" required="required" maxlength="255" id="user_zip"></div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FormHelper::setTemplates()` doesn't overwrite the complete existing set of templates, it merges it with the given templates, ie the `input` template set with the second call, will remain changed.

You either have to `push()` to (store) and `pop()` from (restore) the template stack using the underlying templater to avoid that:

```
$this->Form->templater()->push();
$this->Form->templater()->add($bootstrapTemplateInputGroup);
$this->Form->templater()->pop();
```

or use the `FormHelper::create()` method's `templates` option to apply the templates to the specific `FormHelper::control()` call(s) only:

```
echo $this->Form->control('title', ['templates' => $bootstrapTemplate, /*...*/]);
echo $this->Form->control('price', ['templates' => $bootstrapTemplateInputGroup, /*...*/]);
echo $this->Form->control('user_zip', ['templates' => $bootstrapTemplate, /*...*/]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > Helper > Form > Options for Control](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#options-for-control)**
- **[API > \Cake\View\StringTemplate](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.View.StringTemplate.html)**

Comment: Thanks... I went for the `echo $this->Form->control('user_zip', ['templates' => $bootstrapTemplate, ... ` solution. It's easier and much more readable.